# Adding additional column to the result of relationship in eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I have two models. Both of them are pivots because they join other tables. But also they have a relationship with themselves.

```
class CompanyUser extends Pivot
{
    protected $table = 'company_user';

    public function companyUserProducts() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\CompanyUserProduct','company_user_id');
    }

}

class CompanyUserProduct extends Pivot
{
    protected $table = 'company_user_product';

    public function companyUser() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\CompanyUser','company_user_id');
    }
    
}
```

I want to get all entities of CompanyUserProduct but with the additional column `user_id` from `CompanyUser`, so I can do `pluck('user_id')` on the collection and get all IDs at once. Is it possible to do it in Eloquent, or must I use Query Builder?

```
$companyUsers = CompanyUserProduct::with('companyUser')->get();
```

Comment: Is `...with('companyUser:id,user_id')->get()` not working? You should be able to `pluck('companyUser.user_id') I think. Or maybe you should `flatten` the collection before you can `pluck`.

Comment: Didn't test, but maybe you can do something like this: ```CompanyUserProduct::with('companyUser')->addSelect('company_user.user_id')->get()``` ?

Comment: company_user_product table's `company_user_id` references `user_id` or `id` column on company_user table

Comment: Thank you @MohamedMufeed. Your solution helped. Can you post answer and I will accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```php
$companyUsers = CompanyUserProduct::with('companyUser:id,user_id')->get();
```

To retrieve the `CompanyUserProduct` along with the `id` and `user_id` of `compantUser`.

Note: whatever your `primary key` for `companyUser` - make sure you select it as well. (In this case assumed to be `id`)

Once you retrieve the collection, the `user_id` will be under `companyUser` for each `CompanyUserProduct`

So, you can pluck it using dot notation.

eg:

```php
$userIds = $companyUsers->pluck('companyUser.user_id');
```